# How to debug java code in AWS cluster

Tags: debugging, amazon-web-services, remote-debugging, apache-storm

We are working on Apache storm with kafka in AWS cluster.
As a developer i want to have a local environment setup to debug the code.
But i checked the prerequisites of Horton sandbox,it requires above 8GB RAM.So we thought to have debugging environment using AWS itself.

Let me know how to do debugging in AWS ot is there any best way to have sandbox with less ram or any another best procedure to follow.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vagrant to manage your EC2 instances, so you can always get the nominated  environment for developing

Here is the open source code: 
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

The [README](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/blob/master/README.md) gives the detail on how to set it with Vagrant.